# SQL Server Mean(Avg) of Column Grouped by DatePart

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I am trying to run the following command in a VB language (Some Microsoft based program dev program).
The sql line must Make the average of a column (Tag1 in this case) for every Hour.

```
> sql = " Select DATEPART(hh, Time_Stamp) as Hour, AVG(Tag1) as Mean
> From TREND001 Where CONVERT(DATETIME2, Time_Stamp, 120) >= Convert
> (DATETIME2, '" & startDate & "', 120) AND CONVERT(DATETIME2,
> Time_Stamp, 120) < DATEADD (DAY,1, CONVERT (DATETIME2, '" & endDate &
> "', 120) ) Group BY DATEPART(hh, Time_Stamp)"
```

The result is:

> Column 'TREND001.Time_Stamp' is invalid in the select list because it
>   is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
Select DATEPART(hh, Time_Stamp) as Hour, AVG(Tag1) as Mean From TREND001 Where CONVERT(DATETIME2, Time_Stamp, 120) >= Convert (DATETIME2, '" & startDate & "', 120) AND CONVERT(DATETIME2, Time_Stamp, 120) < DATEADD (DAY,1, CONVERT (DATETIME2, '" & endDate & "', 120) ) Group BY DATEPART(hh, Time_Stamp)
```

Comment: Already tried it. Same result. Also I think it will make it worse, giving the fact that Order By is executed before Select

Comment: No you cant use alias name in group by

Comment: @user3864308 Is that the exact query you are runnig? Or did you modify it a bit? This error seems doubtful .

Comment: @sagi Yes. This is the exact the query.

Comment: @sagi For some reason, I got it to work now. I did a copy from the answer and changed the Group By. I'm Searching to see what was different.

Comment: I think earlier you were using Order By Instead of Group By as mentioned in your first comment, Please mark it as answer if this query worked

Comment: @Ashu Edit your answer to Group BY DATEPART(hh, Time_Stamp). I will accept it. Thank You